# removing values from a file

Tags: shell, unix

```
 EXTRA_JAVA_PROPERTIES="${EXTRA_JAVA_PROPERTIES} -DproxySet=true     -Dhttp.proxyHost=abc-proxy.company.com -Dhttp.proxyPort=80 -Dhttps.proxyHost=abc-proxy.company.com -Dhttps.proxyPort=80 -Dhttp.nonProxyHosts=localhost|*.company.com|100.10.10.12|jcd-ab-unix3.ww.corp.test.com|100.12.33.43|jcd-al-lnx87.am.corp.test.com|111.12.333.33"
export EXTRA_JAVA_PROPERTIES
# Set final environment user overrides, if available.

if [ -f ${DOMAIN_HOME}/bin/setUserOverridesLate.sh ] ; then
    . ${DOMAIN_HOME}/bin/setUserOverridesLate.sh
fi

# IF USER_MEM_ARGS the environment variable is set, use it to override ALL MEM_ARGS values

if [ "${USER_MEM_ARGS}" != "" ] ; then
    MEM_ARGS="${USER_MEM_ARGS}"
    export MEM_ARGS
fi

JAVA_PROPERTIES="${JAVA_PROPERTIES} ${EXTRA_JAVA_PROPERTIES}"
export JAVA_PROPERTIES
```

I want to remove following keys and values from the setDomainEnv.sh file
    -DproxySet
    -Dhttp.proxyPort
    -Dhttps.proxyHost
    -Dhttps.proxyPort
    -Dhttp.nonProxyHosts

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `sed` command to replace the string with an empty string.

`sed -i 's/-DproxySet//g' setDomainEnv.sh`

This will replace **-DproxySet** with empty string. This will make the change in actual file.

You can run a for loop for each of the values you want to remove and use the above `sed` command with it. 
OR you can also pass multiple expressions in sed, like 
`sed -e 's/-DproxySet//g' -e 's/-Dhttp.proxyHost//g' setDomainEnv.sh`